# Data from Firebase not showing up in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a tableview with a custom cell and it is getting the data from firebase. When I run the app, nothing is showing in the tableview. None of my print statements after my second database reference work, but the database reference is correct.
Here is my database structure(I simplified it as best I could):

```
{
   "Classes" : {
"-LiGRdN6aoXHfE9wn0TW" : {
  "Students" : {
    "J526G6DB3uONdNM2hzgDYdgokd93" : "J526G6DB3uONdNM2hzgDYdgokd93",
    "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22"
  },
  "class_info" : {
    "date_clasname" : "mm",
    "room_number" : "jj",
    "subject" : "Science",
    "teacher" : "mm",
    "uid" : "-LiGRdN6aoXHfE9wn0TW"
  }
},
"-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi" : {
  "Students" : {
    "J526G6DB3uONdNM2hzgDYdgokd93" : "J526G6DB3uONdNM2hzgDYdgokd93",
    "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22"
  },
  "class_info" : {
    "date_clasname" : "mm",
    "room_number" : "jjhh",
    "subject" : "Science",
    "teacher" : "mm",
    "uid" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  }
},
  "Users" : {
"J526G6DB3uONdNM2hzgDYdgokd93" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-LiGRdN6aoXHfE9wn0TW" : "-LiGRdN6aoXHfE9wn0TW",
    "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  },
  "User_info" : {
    "email" : "bob@gmail.com",
    "grade" : "9",
    "name" : "bob"
  }
```

Here is my code for the activity that is displaying the info in the UITableView:

```
  class class_custom_cell2: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cc: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var teacher: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var rn: UILabel!    
}      
class Home: UIViewController , UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
var classes2 = [Class]()
@IBOutlet weak var tb_yourClasses: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       tb_yourClasses.delegate = self
        tb_yourClasses.dataSource = self

        fetchClass2()
    }

    func fetchClass2() {


        Database.database().reference().child("Users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).child("Classes").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

       if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? String{
                let class_id = dictionary
         print(class_id)
       let b = Database.database().reference().child("Classes").child(class_id).child("class_info")
        print(b)
        b.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let class_object = Class(dictionary: dictionary)
                print(class_object)
                self.classes2.append(class_object)



                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    self.tb_yourClasses.reloadData()
                })
            }

            }, withCancel: nil)

            }

        }, withCancel: nil)
    }

    @objc func handleCancel() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(classes2)
        return classes2.count
       }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! class_custom_cell2

        let data_class2 = classes2[indexPath.row]
    print(data_class2)
        cell.cc?.text = data_class2.date_clasname
        cell.teacher?.text = data_class2.teacher
        cell.rn?.text = data_class2.room_number

        return cell
    }   
 }
```

Thank you and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: No there aren't any prints(class_object) @Sh_Khan

Comment: Is tableView::cellForRowAt() being called?  I'm wondering if you also need to get the number of sections.  In this case 1

Comment: I updated the question...it is a problem with the way I am retrieving the data from firebase after the second database reference @LorenRogers

Comment: Can you help me please? @Sh_Khan